# Salesforce to Salesforce with Duplicate Management: How to detect duplicate lead error?

Tags: duplicate-management, salesforce2salesforce

I have S2S set up between two SF orgs (Source and Target).  When a lead is created in the Source org then S2S creates it in the Target org.

However, the Target org has Duplicate Management set up so that if a user attempts to create a lead that already exists in the org an error is displayed.

If a lead is created in the Source org that exists in the Destination org, when S2S attempts to sync the lead over then the lead doesn't get created.

I would like to be able to detect that the lead wasn't created in the Target org (through a trigger would be ideal but I don't think the trigger is fired because the lead never gets created) but so far I haven't had any luck.

Is it possible to detect that the duplicate lead error occurred?